# how to add Windows Phone 8.0 to Mobile_Detect.php class so it detects it

Tags: php, windows-phone-8, user-agent

i have following user agent

> [userAgent] => Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0;
>   Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 925)

but my function

```
if ($detect->isMobile()) {
  //it doesn't come true, it should come here  
}
```

Class Ref# [Mobile Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/blob/master/Mobile_Detect.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have got the solution, the following condition will return windows version

```
 if ($detect->version('Windows Phone')) {
   //will return Windows Phone [VER]
}
```

there is a  `protected static $properties = array()` method